# AngularJS Routing infinite loop in spa model with mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

I have tried a bunch of other posts over the web that seems to be the same problem as mine, but none worked.

I have this menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#Painel/1">Novas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Painel/2">Todas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Painel/3">Finalizadas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Painel/4">Pendentes</a></li>
</ul>
```

Quite simple nav bar. This routing setup:

```
module.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/Painel/:painelId/', 
        {
            templateUrl : function(params)
            {
                return "/Painel/Index/" + params.painelId;
            },
            controller  : 'painelController'
        })
        .otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: "/Painel"
        });
    }]);
}
```

My MVC Controller:

```
public class PainelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int? id))
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And finally my angular controller:

```
module.controller('painelController', ["$scope", "$routeParams", function ($scope, $routeParams)
{
    debugger;
}]);
```

Its a very simple architecture, but angular is looping through its controller infinitely. I took care to set my `templateUrl` relative with `/` as many posts suggested over there, but it didn't worked. It works sending the parameter to the mvc Action, but then it starts the loop stopping forever on the angular's controller `debugger`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem wasn't on the Angular code, but in the MVC's return Action:

```
return View();
```

Since you're working with dynamic content, you don't have to return the full html source(with `html`, `head`, `body` tags...), so I had to change to:

```
return PartialView();
```

What makes totally more sense. Because every request was calling a new angular code, that opened a new request and so on... Then I have created two routes for the opitional parameters(I don't know why it doesn't worked as @Tacoman667 pointed)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that since I did something similar. I created a catchall controller action that served up partial views instead of an action for every view. I placed my angular views in separate cshtml files for organization. Basically I had index.cshtml to serve up the "home" page to start off angular and another action for all the angular routes.

Comment: @Tacoman667 same as I have done. But your answer helped me a lot, too. That is why I have upvoted it. Thank you dude.

Comment: Glad I could help, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that :painelId is not optional and thus you fall into your otherwise() redirect infinitely. Make the :painelId optional like

```
'/Painel/:painelId?/'
```

And this should fix your issue. If you are not using a version of Angular that supports optional parameters then you will need to add another when() to cover the '/Painel' route.

Comment: Thank you dude, I will check that. I'm using a fresh mint version, downloaded yesterday.

Comment: It worked, but the url now get this sufix `%3F/` that is the `?` code.

Comment: You need to register that route, not use it like that in the address bar.

    $routeProvider
        .when('/Painel/:painelId?/', 
        {
            templateUrl : function(params)
            {
                return "/Painel/Index/" + params.painelId;
            },
            controller  : 'painelController'
        })
        .otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: "/Painel"
        });
    }]);

Comment: I have done it. Further, the `params.painelId` comes with `?` at the end, I have to remove it to return a clean url, but event doing this, the url becomes wierd.